# SQL Query issues: invalid identifier

Tags: c#, sql, database, oracle

I've been working on a delete function for a while now, and I cannot get past this error.

Delete Failed ORA-00904 "SYSTEM"."DATA"."DATAROWVIEW": invalid identifier

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string yesNoPrompt = "Are you sure you want to delete this patient?";
        const string caption = "";
        var result = MessageBox.Show(yesNoPrompt, caption,
                                     MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                     MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            string sql = "DELETE FROM CLIENT WHERE (CLI_LNAME =" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + ")" ;

            try
            {
                string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
                using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())
                {
                    connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
                    connection.Open();

                    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sql, connection);
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }
            catch (System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Delete Failed" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

The table in the database is CLIENT and I am trying to find a specific person by their last name, or CLI_LNAME. I don't think the problem is in the name being passed, but more of how it is being passed.

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like you forgot some ' in `DELETE FROM CLIENT WHERE (CLI_LNAME = '" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')` now your `CLI_LNAME` seems to be a string type

Comment: Do you really have the column `CLI_NAME` in the table ? and also the name should be enclosed in **single quotes**, Thats why its good to use parameterized queries

Comment: That was it.. Something so simple. I must be tired.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing single quote in parameters

```
string sql = "DELETE FROM CLIENT WHERE (CLI_LNAME ='" + listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() + "')" ;
```

Its better if you could use [Parameterized query](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/articles/parameters.html)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()` returns "SYSTEM"."DATA"."DATAROWVIEW". You probably want to access a specific item of the `DataRowView` that's the `SelectedItem`, not the entire DataRowView object itself. Maybe `listBox1.SelectedItem[0].ToString()` is what you want?.

Also you have to add quotes as @Habib.OSU mentions.

And the obligatory sql injection warning: Don't concatenate user inputs into SQL string. It opens up for [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use parameterized queries.

Comment: Noted. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 1):

Your query gets translated to

```
DELETE FROM CLIENT WHERE (CLI_LNAME = SYSTEM.DATA.DATAROWVIEW)
```

Due to the missing single quotes and hence its trying to find a column named `SYSTEM.DATA.DATAROWVIEW` which is not present in the `Client` table. hence the error.

When you use single quotes then its looking for the text in that particular column

```
DELETE FROM CLIENT WHERE (CLI_LNAME = 'PatientName') // Now its not a column as such
```

Use Parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Reading on it now. Thanks for your input.